# Handling deadlock in UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have run into a deadlock issue and there is no clear solution to me on how to resolve it. I have the query ordered the same way on every execution which I thought would prevent other processes locking it as well. Keep in mind this query can be hit dozens of times a second.

The deadlocking query is as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
update `user_events`
    set `latest` = 0
    where (`resource_id` = 105
      and `latest` = 1
      and `member_id` = 52632)
      and `eventtype` in ('user_watched', 'user_unwatched');
COMMIT
```

PK of table: `id` (not needed in query)
Indexes: `resource_id`,`member_id`, `latest`

Following this query we then insert the new row with latest set to `1`. So the job of the previous query is to set latest = `0` for any of the given events so we only care about the latest event for either of the two shown.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the explain plan? Is update using the index?

Answer (score 0):

You need a *composite* index:

```
INDEX(resource_id, latest, member_id, eventtype)
```

(The order of the columns is probably not important.)

Without such an index, finding the row is slower and more rows are being locked than necessary.

Having the index will eliminate *most* deadlocks.  But you should still check for errors and replay the transaction if you get any error.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I currently have a composite key on `resource_id, member_id and eventtype` but not `latest` as I didn't know `latest` was required giving I don't select on it but instead just update on it. Worth also noting that we are using InnoDB as the DB engine.

Comment: @XanT - then this might be best:  `INDEX(resource_id, member_id, event_type, latest)`.  But since `latest` keeps changing, your 3-column index might be better.  Please update your Question by adding `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so all of us can see all of the indexes.